# Parse data from Parse.com in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am new to parse.com and android studio. I tried to create a table in parse by simply giving some test data but when the app runs the emulator says `"unfortunately the app has stopped"`.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
public class fresh_app extends Activity {
    Button b1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fresh_app);
        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
                testObject.put("foo", "bar");
                testObject.saveInBackground();
            }
        });
    }
```

The gradle dependicies are :

```
compile files('libs/Parse-1.10.3/Parse-1.10.3.jar')
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
```

Comment: you need to post your log

Comment: post your logcat pls

Comment: see LogCat for the StackTrace of the exception. It will show where is the problem

Comment: --------- beginning of crash
10-26 17:54:57.293    1933-1933/com.example.anand.fresh_ap E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.anand.fresh_ap, PID: 1933
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.anand.fresh_ap/com.example.anand.fresh_ap.fresh_app}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context)`
            at os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)    @VladMatvienko  @sakir   @Wesley this is what my logcat says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, LogCat said it all - You need to put `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);` before `Parse.initialize` in Your class that extends `Application` (inside `onCreate()` ):

```
public class ParseApp extends Application{

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, key1, key2);
}
}
```

Also, no need for compiling files - You could just do:
`compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3'`